# scala Convert String to tuple and insert into list

Tags: scala, tuples

code:

```
var tup = ""
var l1 = new ListBuffer[String]()    
tup=""
for (element1 <- tds) {
tup += element1.text + "|"
}
l1 += tup
l1
```

Output:

```
ListBuffer(STANDINGS|CONFERENCE|OVERALL|, ACC|W-L|GB|PCT|W-L|PCT|STRK|, North Carolina|14-2|--|.875|29-5|.853|L1|, Duke|13-3|1|.813|27-6|.818|L1|)
```

Now this is a list of string. I want it to be a list of tuple.

Comment: Could you give more details? What does it mean `to tuple`? What is the Tuple type? Also, please, format your code in proper way. Thanks

Comment: Tuple type is string, but the size is varying.

Comment: So if size is not constant, why do you want it to be a tuple? How are you going to use it later? Maybe `List[List[String]]` would be better for you? Please, provide more context to get better answers.

Comment: These are the records and I just want to refer to each element in the record. Suggest me some other wy to do this. For example, record1,element1 would be STANDINGS. If the index starts from 1. record2, element3 would be GB.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The thing you're looking for (assuming you want to split on `|`) is not well-typed. You would get

```
ListBuffer(("Standings", "Conference", "Overall"), ("ACC", "W-L", "GB", ...), ...)
```

The first element would be `Tuple3[String, String, String]`. The second would be `Tuple7[String, ... String]`, and `ListBuffer`, like all collections, can't have heterogeneous types. You can get a `ListBuffer` of arrays, though.

```
l1.map(_.split("|"))
```

Comment: ListBuffer(("Standings", "Conference", "Overall"), ("ACC", "W-L", "GB", ...), ...). This is how am expecting my output.

Comment: if I use l1.map(_.split("|")), am getting, List([Ljava.lang.String;@6f1fba17)List([Ljava.lang.String;@185d8b6, [Ljava.lang.String;@67784306)List([Ljava.lang.String;@335eadca,...

Comment: That's exactly what I just said. The thing you're expecting is *not well typed*. It doesn't exist in Scala, because Scala is a statically typed language. You would get some worthless type like `ListBuffer[AnyRef]` that you wouldn't be able to do anything with.

Comment: To clarify, with lists, `List(1, 2, 3)` and `List(1, 2)` have the same type, but with tuples, `(1, 2, 3)` and `(1, 2)` have *different types*. This is part of the way tuples are defined and it's why you can't do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually, the thing is, these are the records and I want to refer to each element in the record. That's the ultimate requirement.

Comment: The records would be,                   
STANDINGS|CONFERENCE|OVERALL|, 
ACC|W-L|GB|PCT|W-L|PCT|STRK|, 
North Carolina|14-2|--|.875|29-5|.853|L1|, 
Duke|13-3|1|.813|27-6|.818|L1|,

Comment: Instead of list and tuple, can u pls suggest me some other way to get it done

Comment: The correct way to do what you're trying to do would be with arrays or lists, since the structure has variable length. Why are you opposed to a solution involving lists?

Comment: Ya, I will try lists.

Answer (score 0):

I used `List[List[String]]`. And now am able to refer to each element.
Am adding Lists to a List like this

```
(1::2::Nil)::(5::7::Nil)::Nil
```

Now my output is like this

```
List(List(STANDINGS, CONFERENCE, OVERALL), List(ACC, W-L, GB, PCT, W-L, PCT, STRK))
```